# WPF add element to user control via DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

i try add controls via DependencyProperty, first have this user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Common.Controls.SaveFromSource" ...>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In code behing has this:

```
namespace Project.Common.Controls
{
    public partial class SaveFromSource : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Grid", typeof(Grid), typeof(FilterFromSource));

        public Grid Grid
        {
            get { return (Grid)GetValue(GridProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridProperty, value); }
        }

        public SaveFromSource()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (this.Grid != null)
            {
                this.grid = this.Grid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in new window have this:

```
<controls:SaveFromSource>
    <controls:SaveFromSource.Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="CONTROL 1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="CONTROL 2"/>
        </Grid>
    </controls:SaveFromSource.Grid>
</controls:SaveFromSource>
```

The question is, why textbox's dont show in user control?

** I need to dynamically add controls to the user control in order to reuse code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is all wrong. First of all, the Grid property is always null in the control's constructor. It will only be set later, after the constructor has finished. Second, assigning the value of the Grid property to the grid field does nothing. You would have to set the control's Content property. Finally, what is the reason for doing all this, when there is only that Grid Content? Having a UserControl seems pointless in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

To expand on Clemen's comment, you don't need that Grid DP. Just do this in your UserControl instead:

```
<!--<Grid Grid.Row="0"/>    <--- get rid of this        -->
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
```

And then in your parent class add the content directly:

```
<controls:SaveFromSource>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="CONTROL 1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="CONTROL 2"/>
    </Grid>
</controls:SaveFromSource>
```

If your reason for doing this is that you need more than one content then you'll have to add additional DPs for that to your UserControl and bind to it in your XAML with ContentControls.

Comment: The ContentPresenter would only make sense in a ControlTemplate. If you set a UserControl's Content, the previous Content from its XAML would be replaced, including the ContentPresenter.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the correction, I actually meant to say ContentControls. Fixed now.

Comment: Simply putting a ContentPresenter in the UserControl's XAML - as you show here - would still not work.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, And how can I access the controls from c #? I'm testing and don't have access to this.mycontrol.property

Comment: @pedroPG try posting as separate question, the answer will depend on your usage scenario i;e. what do you have access to?